# Script for finding folder that contains a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm working on a portable development enviroment, so I need to find the route of the bins.I have tried with this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir mysqld.exe /b /s') do set mysql=%%a
```

It returns `A:\test\mysql-5.7.24-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe` but I want to get only the folder, like this  `A:\test\mysql-5.7.24-winx64\bin\`, how can I achieve this?.

Comment: Based upon the advice provided in the supplied answers, if you're searching on the same drive that your batch file is located, then be sure to include its drive letter, as the code provided is based upon the current directory, _(which may not necessarily be the same)_. **`For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D-L "%~d0\mysqld.exe" 2^>Nul')Do Set "mysqldir=%%~dpA"`** or **`For /R %~d0\ %%A In (mysqld.exe)Do Set "mysqldir=%%~dpA"`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use modifiers (described in `for /?`):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir mysqld.exe /b /s') do set "mysql=%%~dpa"
echo %mysql%
```

`%%~dpa` returns **d**rive and **p**ath only.

Same without using `dir` (as `for /r` can recursively search for (a) file(s)):

```
for /r "c:\startfolder" %%a in (mysqld.exe) do set "mysql=%%~dpa"
```

`"c:\startfolder"` is the start point for recursive search (you can omit it to search within the current folder and it's subfolders)

Note: if more there is than one matching file, the variable will hold the last finding.

Comment: Thank you, the second option It's a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subroutine with a parameter.
[read about parameters here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Something like this. Remove what I added for display.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir mysqld.exe /b /s') do call :GetFolder "%%a"
echo(%mysql%
pause
goto :eof

:GetFolder
REM 1=Filespec
set "MySQL=%~dp1"
goto :eof
```